# Get restaurants near my location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-latitude

I've tried to find a suitable `Google Places API` that takes in `My Location` and returns the nearby `restaurants`.

Currently, I've been able to find only restaurants in a "particular" city.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=*MyKey*
```

Is there a way of implementing this?

Comment: What do you mean by implement?

Comment: Implementing Google Places API that takes in "My Location"[and not my city] and returns the nearby "restaurants"..

Comment: are you creating any web application, if then use any preferable language i:e php.

Comment: see the docs. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=49.260691,-123.137784&radius=500&sensor=false&key=*PlacesAPIKey*&types=restaurant
```

types is optional

Comment: Yes. This way what I was looking for. I'd had already found it but was having trouble in assigning the "lat" and "long". I wanted to make the script automatically determine the "lat" and "long".